# Вывод изображений галереи с обратной сортировкой

Tags: wordpress

Код помогает вывести изображения в виде галереи, которые берет из ***кастомного поста***:

```
$query = new WP_Query([
  'post_type' => 'works',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
]);
if( $query->have_posts() ): while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
foreach( pods_field( 'works', get_the_ID(), 'gallery_works') as $img  ) :
endforeach;
endwhile; endif;
```

Как сделать обратную сортировку изображений, чтобы последние добавленные фотографии отображались в начале галереи?

Пробовал добавлять параметры `orderby` и `order` с различными значениями, но **не работает**, видимо из-за того, что изображения подтягиваются из кастомного поста.

ID кастомного поля - `gallery_works`, через которое в посте загружены фотографии.

Comment: Вы хотите отсортировать посты в обратном порядке или кастомное поле в этих постах?

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Нужно, чтобы выводились в обратном порядке изображения. Они находятся в галереи в виде файлов изображений. Галерея находится в кастомном поле кастомного поста. Т.е. другими словами - есть один пост с одним кастомным полем в виде галереи. Нужно, чтобы последние добавленные в эту галерею фотографии отображались во фронтэнде первыми.

Comment: ID кастомного поля не может быть текстом. Это сквозная цифровая нумерация. Суррогатный ключ.

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать обратную сортировку изображений, чтобы последние
> добавленные фотографии отображались в начале галереи?

Как-то так:

```
$query = new WP_Query([
  'post_type' => 'works',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby' => 'ID', 
  'order' => 'DESC'
]);
```

См. описание функции https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#orderby

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку. Но, пожалуйста, читайте внимательнее пост, в котором я написал, что пробовал различные значения параметров orderby и order, и те, о которых вы сказали - первым делом. Что-то не дает срабатывать сортировке, я подозреваю, это могжет быть само кастомное поле, в котором непосредственно загружены фотографии.

Comment: @Dmitry ID у ВП сквозное. А значит по нему и строиться сортировка. Если по каким-то причинам что-то не так выводится - значит тут уже надо искать проблему. Возможно кеширование, возможно ещё что-то. Делай вывод промежуточных результатов и всё увидишь.